# wp_mail() won't send mail when it's a variable, only when hard coded

Tags: email, wp-mail

I have coded a "follow post" script to which I wanna add the functionality of sending the user an email if a post they have followed has been updated. My script only sends an email if I hardcode an email into wp_mail(), e.g.

```
wp_mail('mail@domain.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
```

But when I when it dynamic with all the users who has followed the post, it doesn't send any email at all, my code looks like:

http://pastebin.com/yPirRwKn or:

```
function favorites_send_email($postid, $post) {    

if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
}

if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
    return;
}

$slug = 'journal';

if ( $slug != $post->post_type ) {
    return;
}

$posttitle = get_the_title($postid);
$posturl = get_permalink($postid);

$headers = "From: NAME <no-reply@domain.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$subject = 'En af dine favoritter er blevet opdateret!';
$message = "Læs mere på nedenstående link (husk du skal logge på, hvis du er logget ud):\r\n";
$message .= "<a href='" . $posturl . "'>" . $posttitle . "</a>\r\n";

global $wpdb;

$table_name = get_table_name('favorite_posts');

$getusers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT userid FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE postid = " . $postid);

foreach ($get_users as $get_user) {
    $theuser = get_userdata($get_user->userid);

    $email_data[] = array('name' => $theuser->display_name, 'email' => $theuser->user_email);
}

foreach($email_data as $data) {
    wp_mail($data["email"], $subject, $message, $headers);
}
}

add_action('save_post', 'favorites_send_email', 10, 3);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: since you are not trying to send to the same people when you hardcode and when you generate dinamycally it is impossible to claim that there is any problem with the dynamic code. Most likely you try to send to many people and your host blocks it.

Comment: Please do not use external links in your questions. When those are gone, the question will be hard to impossible to understand. File an [edit] and put the relevant parts here. If the content is the same, simply remove the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$getusers -> $get_users
```

Simple mistake of wrong variable use!